# How to know that thread is running in objective c?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am starting a thread using detachNewThreadSelector. i dont want to start thread everytime. i need to check  that thread is already running, if that thread is already running then don't start the thread, if not then only start the thread. can anyone help me how to check the thread state?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a good way to keep hold of state. I'm thinking you are better off doing this with GCD.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the running state of thread using  `isExecuting`,

```
BOOL isStillRunning = [yourThreadObject isExecuting];
```

Answer (score -1):

Start the thread, don't let it terminate.  You may then reasonably assume that the thread exists, (which is what you acctually want?), without actually checking it.